# Excel - format a cell so that it display the arithmetic expression of another cell

Tags: excel, expression

Let's say in A1 I have "=25/5", after I hit enter I get the result in A1. Is it possible to have in B1 the arithmetic expression itself (also with VBA if needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current `Excel` versions provide [FORMULATEXT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). So the formula

```
=FORMULATEXT(A1)
```

gets the formula text of `A1`.

For `Excel` versions which do not provide that function, the folowing `VBA` user defined function can be used:

```
Public Function getformula(r As Range) As String
 getformula = r.Formula
End Function
```

Usage in sheet would be:

```
=getformula(A1)
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know this simple function! Thank you very much!!!